# can't run a simple division on STM32

Tags: c, stm32

I'm trying to set a simple division in a project, on STM32F10x here what I've done  :

say I got a float variable:

```
float f =0.0; 

.............
```

when I use `f` this way :

```
f = 20/5 ;
```

the program can't  use the value of `f` which is the result of the division,  I'm using this value  in multiple other functions in the Program, but none of them works meaning that I'dont get an error but the program doesn't work .
 but when set  the value :

```
f = 4 ;
```

everything works fine !
any idea why ?
I've used :
 f = (float) 20/5 ;

Comment: are you sure you write what you meant? I did not understand your question.

Comment: What does "can't use" mean? You didn't say what the value of `f = 20/5` actually is.

Comment: `program can't use the value`...please elaborate.

Comment: `program doesn't work`....please elaborate.

Comment: The question is not greatly worded - most likely due to English as 2nd language issues (and could no double be improved with edits).  But it is a valid and valuble question (with a good answer) - it does not deserve a close.  I.e distinguish "good question badly worded" from "bad question"

Comment: @Ricibob What language issues? I understand everything said just fine. Giving a fuzzy problem description as "my program does not work" is not related to language difficulties. There is no clear problem description, not enough details and the problem cannot be reproduced with what is posted here. Furthermore, the accepted answer is not valuable either as it is incorrect! This whole post is unsalvageable in its current state and needs a radical edit by the OP. How you find an unanswerable question with an incorrect answer _valuable_ to future readers is really beyond me.

Comment: @Lundin At the time I made the comment it appeared the question was valid with a valid answer - although it now appears that may not be the case - in which case the queustion maybe flawed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler treats all floating point numbers without a suffix as `double`.

This will blow up on STM32/ARM.

Use a suffix, iow `20.0f`.

The reason your cast works is because the result can be determined at compile time. If not, it will blow up again.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. `20/5` are _integer_ literals, not floating point literals. `f = 4 ;` is completely equivalent to `f = 20/5;` and should yield identical machine code unless the compiler is broken. There are no implicit promotions to double anywhere.

Comment: @Lundin: I missed that, you are correct. Not sure why it got marked as the answer unless there is some subtlety being missed.

Comment: The question was wrongly made, the answer was also wrong, so anything can happen.  Let's leave it as such.  The "undefined behaviour" thing is making good progress here.  Please, this is just a comment, don't blame me. :)